# Kafka Consumer batch consumption with only 1 consumer for multi partitioned topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am consuming from Kafka topic with an Azkaban job. I don't want to implement the long-running `while(true)` loop as the topic is low throughput. I also want to ensure at-least-once delivery semantics.

The topic has 5 partitions. Is there any way for my single thread Azkaban job consumer to poll all partitions, fetch data, process them, and terminate after committing?
So far I have come up with this:

```html
//set "enable.auto.commit": "false" in the properties
Consumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(kafkaConfig.getTopicName()));
long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
long end = t+15000;
try{
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            log.info("offset = {}, key = {}, partition = {}", record.offset(), record.key(), record.partition());
            // do my processing involving some DB calls
        }
        kafkaConsumer.commitSync();
    }
} catch (Exception e){
    log.error(e.toString());
} finally {
    kafkaConsumer.close();
}
```

Looking for suggestions for a more elegant solution. Any resources on understanding how a single Kafka consumer can consume more than one partition in a poll. Does it read from only one partition in a poll and when it moves to the second?